# Better Kotlin way of getting roles from JWT Claims

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code, that gets user roles from a `io.jsonwebtoken.Claims` object

```
val claims = jwtUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(authToken)
val rolesMap = claims.get("role", ArrayList::class.java)
val roles = ArrayList<Role>()
for (rolemap in rolesMap) {
    roles.add(Role.valueOf((rolemap as LinkedHashMap<String, String>)["authority"] as String))
}
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to get the role(s) as `String` in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this. The main difference being the use of the higher order function `map`, which iterates a collection applying a function to create a new collection of the same size but of a new type.

Also, unless you need the intermidiate parts of the function to be assigned to variables for debugging/logging purposes then you can simply ommit assigning values and just chain function calls, but it can make it less easy to read (debatable):

```
return jwtUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(authToken)
              .get("role", ArrayList::class.java)
              .map {
                    Role.valueOf((it as Map<String, String>)["authority"])
              }
```

Comment: FWIW, for slightly more conciseness, you could cast to `Map<String, String>` instead.  And *presumably*, the final cast to `String` is redundant?

Comment: Yea, I think the final cast is redundant, but I didn't want to remove it as I didn't actually compile the code I posted as answer so I'd rather leave a redundant cast in (which will be removed by compiler more than likely) than to post a non compiling answer. 

And yea, casting to the `Map<String, String>` would be a better idea, unless the functionality `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` is required.